# Is it possible to get Extended Support for Microsoft Internet Explorer 11 for Communities Only?

Tags: community, internet-explorer

Is it possible to enable `Extended Support for Accessing Lightning Experience Using Microsoft Internet Explorer 11` for Lightning Communities only?

Such that the rest of Salesforce Lightning does not have it enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, normal [IE 11 support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000233325&language=en_US&type=1) is available without Extended Support:

> ## Are Salesforce Classic, Console, or Communities affected by this change?
>
> There is no impact to Salesforce Classic, as IE11 will remain a supported browser. This includes the use of Lightning components in Visualforce pages running in Salesforce Classic.
>
> Additionally, there is no impact to Communities (Visualforce and Lightning template-based), Salesforce Console for Salesforce Classic, Lightning for Outlook, or standalone Lightning apps (e.g. myapp.app).

I can't test this, but it seems that IE 11 support could be disabled without affecting your communities.

Comment: Then why is my public community page is totally blank when viewed from IE 11... :S

Comment: I do get this error in the console log `Action failed: forceCommunity:seoAssistant$controller$init [Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach']
Callback failed: serviceComponent://ui.comm.runtime.components.aura.components.siteforce.controller.PubliclyCacheableComponentLoaderController/ACTION$getPageComponent`

Comment: That's not consistent with what this text says... either the text is wrong or the feature is broken. This might be a cause to raise a case?

Comment: There was a JavaScript error which was stopping anything from rendering in IE 11